# Configuring Global Access for GKE Ingress Controller

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I am trying to configure global access for the Internal Load Balancer provisioned by the GKE Ingress Controller to enable access from all GCP regions.

This is easy enough to do with the "networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-allow-global-access: "true"" annotation in the service YAML while setting up an Internal Load Balancer service.

However, I cannot find any documentation on how to specify a similar annotation while defining an Ingress YAML.

Patching the forwarding rules created once the ingress is deployed is not an option due to my security setup - I need a solution that works while deploying the ingress in GKE.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey, were you able to find a solution for this??

Comment: Yes: We had two major requirements:
1) Use some form of network frontend without external access (eliminating the External HTTP load balancer as an option)....but still allow global access from all GCP regions
2) Be able to perform routing to different K8s services based on path.

We ended up configuring Envoy with an internal TCP load balancer to provide the global access as well as path based routing we needed. Here is a good reference: https://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-use-envoy-as-a-load-balancer-in-kubernetes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal GKE Ingress actually provisions an Internal HTTPS load balancers which is not the same as the internal TCP/UDP load balancer created for K8s Services with "Type: Load Balancer".  Unlike internal TCP/UDP load balancers, the interna HTTPS load balancer does not yet support global access.

Comment: Is it still the same, or some development has occurred on this front? I also have the same problem, where I cannot access the service from a different region.

Comment: Please see my comment to the original question above....we ended up using Envoy.

Comment: Global access for internal HTTPS load balancer is on the roadmap, but it's not out yet.

Comment: It looks like global access for internal http(s) LBs is now supported. See [docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal#global-access).

Comment: @Basti could you please suggest how can we turn on Global access using k8s with Ingress. which annotation should we use?

Comment: @sharad jain There is no support for ingress yet, but if you are in gcp you can use the new k8s gateway api: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-gateway-resources#configure_global_access Just create a `gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/Gateway` and a `networking.gke.io/v1/GCPGatewayPolicy` with `spec.default.allowGlobalAccess: true`. To fully replace an ingress you'll also need a `gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/HTTPRoute`. Checkout https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/ Infos came from Google Cloud support. Enable Gateway API on your cluster first.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments I left on another answer: Google now [supports global access](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal#global-access) for their internal https load balancers. The settings has to be enabled while creating the load balancer and cannot be modified after creation.

As of April 2023 GCP k8s ingress do not yet have an annotation to enable global access. Google Cloud support suggested to use a [`GCPGatewayPolicy`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-gateway-resources#configure_global_access) from the k8s gateway api.

Here is how I implemented this:

```yaml
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: internal-https-global-access-gateway
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  # google kubernetes engine layer 7 regional internal load balancer
  # see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gatewayclass-capabilities
  gatewayClassName: gke-l7-rilb
  listeners:
  - name: internal-https-global-access-gateway-listener
    protocol: HTTPS
    port: 443
    tls:
      certificateRefs:
      - kind: Secret
        name: $internal-ingress-certificate
  addresses:
  - type: NamedAddress
    value: $my-local-static-ip-address-name
---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: GCPGatewayPolicy
metadata:
  name: internal-https-global-access-gateway-policy
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  default:
    # this GCPGatewayPolicy exists only to enable global access on the Gateway's LB
    allowGlobalAccess: true
  targetRef:
    group: gateway.networking.k8s.io
    kind: Gateway
    name: internal-https-global-access-gateway
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: internal-https-global-access-http-route
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - name: internal-https-global-access-gateway
  rules:
  - backendRefs:
    - name: $my-super-service-name
      port: 80
```

- `$internal-ingress-certificate` is a tls-type secret containing an SSL cert - if you need SSL/TLS.
- `$my-local-static-ip-address-name` is the name of an internal regional static ip address, if you need one.
- `$my-super-service-name` is the name of a k8s service, the traffic should be sent to.

We have a service mesh, so I just sent all traffic to that. If you have routing rules in ingress, you have to adjust the `Gateway` and possibly add more `HTTPRoute`s.

Don't forget to [enable the k8s Gateway API](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways#enable-gateway-existing-cluster) on your cluster before you try to apply any of these objects.